# How to get The Child Folder Name of HKEY_USERS in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, registry

Im Trying to get the installed applications in this registry entry.

> HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-1000\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Win‌​dows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

The below code works, if you replace the registry_Key's First part (where the x's are) with your folder name. But how can i get that folder name so that i can use this code on any computer, since that folder name is different on each pc?

In other words, how will i get this part of the string **S-1-5-21-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-1000**

```
     registry_key = @"> HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-1000\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Win‌​dows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
            {
                foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                    {
                        textBox2.Text += subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why you don't use HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead?

Comment: Don't know why i Didn't think of that... Thanks. 
But say I Really wanted to access it this way, how would you do it (since i cant find any where on the net that shows how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list of the USER profiles availabe to traverse the registry on the HKEY_USERS registry hive you could read and filter the contents of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

However, you need to have permissions to open the registry hive of an user different from the current user (Administrator I think, never done).
If you need only to check the CURRENT_USER registry, it 's easier to use directly the key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Win‌​dows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```